# Where does the external library, downloaded by gradle, get stored in an Android project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I need to modify the source code of the [CometChat UI library](https://developer.cometchat.com/docs/android-quick-start).

The documentation says that [the source code can be found in the downloaded SDK package under the Android/CometChat UI](https://developer.cometchat.com/docs/android-modify-ui).

I've unsuccessfully tried to find these files by the path from documentation, even in hidden folders.

The question is how could I get the source code of the whole external library? Where is it stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where does the external library, downloaded by gradle, get stored in an Android project?

It is not stored in the project. It is stored in Gradle's artifact cache. You will find it in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/`, in subdirectories organized by the artifact group and ID.

> The documentation says that the source code can be found in the downloaded SDK package under the Android/CometChat UI.

That documentation seems to be out of date.

> how could I get the source code of the whole external library?

It is possible that source code will be part of what Gradle downloads, depending on how CometChat set up their artifacts. Otherwise, you will need to contact CometChat for developer support.